# Basic React help - nothing displaying

Tags: reactjs

Im currently looking into react and trying to create a basic profile card.

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/jsx">
        var App = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Profile />
                        <Hobbies />
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        var Profile = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div>              
                        <h3>John Smith</h3>
                        <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/' alt='John Smith' />
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        var Hobbies = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h5>My hobbies:</h5>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Coding</li>
                            <li>Designing</li>
                            <li>Guitar</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i open my html page within a browser it doesnt render anything at all. What am i missing?

I'm not getting any errors in my console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using JSX and you need Babel to transpile it into React function calls.

Add this script in your code where you include react and react-dom.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
```

It should work after including this.

Comment: Looks like ES5 `React.createClass` to me.  I think you mean that the OP is using JSX, and needs babel to transpile that.

Comment: Cheers guys, i don't really no what I'm doing.

I'm looking at multiple tutorials so maybe they are using a mixture of Babel and JSX. But adding that babel.js file worked.

Comment: @DavinTryon Sorry my bad. I missed that it was already ES5 code. But yeah, anyways you would need babel to transpile JSX.